# Improving code speed and alternative coding options

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

The code below works with the example data, but is incredibly slow on deployment to real data and thus lots of room for optimization and this is what I am requesting.

The correct results are in the columns *no_overlap_checkin_start* and  *no_overlap_checkin_end*. More about what the code is trying to achieve and about the data is in the section "Aim of code"

I am open to seeing the different optimization options possible, either in base R, Tidyverse, data.table or whatever other cool methods are out there. Shall also appreciate helpful comments (on the slow code, as well as the optimized code) and any tips and tricks. I shall greatly appreciate all improvements.

**Example data:**

```
data_df <- structure(list(Guest_ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2,2, 2, 2, 2), checkin_date = structure(c(17567, 17602, 17644,17707, 17828, 17878, 17927, 17991, 18037, 18137, 18241, 18345,                                                                        18464, 18563, 18667), class = "Date"), boarding_days = c(70,                                                                                                                             50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100                                                                        )), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Code to Optimize**

```
data_df$checkin_date <- as.Date(data_df$checkin_date)


# Format dates
data_df$checkin_start <- as.Date(data_df$checkin_date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
data_df$checkin_end <- data_df$checkin_start + data_df$boarding_days-1

#mark guest's first boarding row by ID
data_df2<- data_df %>%
  group_by(Guest_ID) %>%
  arrange(Guest_ID, checkin_start) %>%  mutate("new_Guest_ID" = if_else(row_number()==1,1,0))%>% 
  as.data.frame()

# Classic loops that need optimization. We iterate over rows
for(i in 1:nrow(data_df2)) {
  # Guest's first row? if yes then copy start date and end date.
  if (data_df2[i,"new_Guest_ID"]==1) {data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]<-data_df2[i,"checkin_start"]
  data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]<-data_df2[i,"checkin_end"]}
  # Where previous boarding ends after the start of the current boarding, then reset the current boarding start date to the 1-day after the end of the previous boarding.
  else {  data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]<-if_else(data_df2[i,"checkin_start"]<=data_df2[i-1,"no_overlap_checkin_end"],data_df2[i-1,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]+1,data_df2[i,"checkin_start"])
  data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]<-data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]+data_df2[i,"boarding_days"]-1}
}
```

**Aim of code**

Given a dataset of guests boarding (each row) in a hotel having the following variables: Guest_ID, checkin_date and boarding_days, for each Guest_ID's record, we can naively calculate a temporary checkout_date and checkin_date as follows:

temp_checkout_date = checkin_date + boarding_days - 1

temp_checkin_date = checkin_date

However, we would like to create new records for each unique guest's boarding having the variables "no_overlap_checkin_start" and "no_overlap_checkin_end" such that there is no overlap in each guest's boarding record i.e., for each guest a boarding record (row), can only start 1 day after the previous row has ended and therefore the (lag(temp_checkout_date) > checkin_date).

If there is no overlap, then the no_overlap_checkin_start and no_overlap_checkin_end are simply calculated as mentioned before in "temporary" calculations.

However, if there is an overlap in a guest's record, i.e., the date of the previous temp_checkout_date >= current row's checkin_date, then set the current no_overlap_checkin_start =  lag(temp_checkout_date, 1) + 1, else retain value of the current row's checkin_date.

Then dynamically calculate the no_overlap_checkin_end based on the updated no_overlap_checkin_start as: no_overlap_checkin_end = no_overlap_checkin_start + boarding_days - 1.

Repeat this procedure for every row of a Guest_ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this, though one row is one day off, not sure if it's my mistake or something in your `data_df2`-generating code.

Both blocks below assume that the data is pre-sorted on `checkin_date` within each `Guest_ID`.

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
data_df %>%
  group_by(Guest_ID) %>%
  mutate(
    no_overlap_checkin_stop = pmax(checkin_date[1] + cumsum(boarding_days) - 1,
                                   checkin_date + boarding_days - 1),
    no_overlap_checkin_start = pmax(lag(no_overlap_checkin_stop) + 1, 
                                    checkin_date,
                                    na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  relocate(no_overlap_checkin_start, .before = no_overlap_checkin_stop) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 15 × 5
#    Guest_ID checkin_date boarding_days no_overlap_checkin_start no_overlap_checkin_stop
#       <dbl> <date>               <dbl> <date>                   <date>                 
#  1        1 2018-02-05              70 2018-02-05               2018-04-15             
#  2        1 2018-03-12              50 2018-04-16               2018-06-04             
#  3        1 2018-04-23              50 2018-06-05               2018-07-24             
#  4        1 2018-06-25              50 2018-07-25               2018-09-12             
#  5        1 2018-10-24              50 2018-10-24               2018-12-12             
#  6        1 2018-12-13              50 2018-12-13               2019-01-31             
#  7        1 2019-01-31              50 2019-02-01               2019-03-21             
#  8        1 2019-04-05              50 2019-04-05               2019-05-24             
#  9        2 2019-05-21             100 2019-05-21               2019-08-28             
# 10        2 2019-08-29             100 2019-08-29               2019-12-06             
# 11        2 2019-12-11             100 2019-12-11               2020-03-19             
# 12        2 2020-03-24             100 2020-03-24               2020-07-01             
# 13        2 2020-07-21             100 2020-07-21               2020-10-28             
# 14        2 2020-10-28             100 2020-10-29               2021-02-04             
# 15        2 2021-02-09             100 2021-02-09               2021-05-19
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(data_df)[,
  no_overlap_checkin_stop := pmax(checkin_date[1] + cumsum(boarding_days) - 1,
                                  checkin_date + boarding_days - 1),
    by = Guest_ID
  ][, no_overlap_checkin_start := pmax(shift(no_overlap_checkin_stop) + 1,
                                       checkin_date, na.rm = TRUE),
    by = Guest_ID]
```

---

## Benchmarking

This data is not huge, so benchmarking may not be truly representative with your data, but with *this* two-guest data:

```r
bench::mark(
orig = { 
  data_df$checkin_start <- as.Date(data_df$checkin_date, format = "%m/%d/%y")
  data_df$checkin_end <- data_df$checkin_start + data_df$boarding_days-1
  data_df2 <- data_df %>%
    group_by(Guest_ID) %>%
    arrange(Guest_ID, checkin_start) %>%
    mutate("new_Guest_ID" = if_else(row_number()==1,1,0))%>% 
  as.data.frame()
  for(i in 1:nrow(data_df2)) {
    if (data_df2[i,"new_Guest_ID"]==1) {
      data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]<-data_df2[i,"checkin_start"]
      data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]<-data_df2[i,"checkin_end"]
    } else { 
    data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]<-if_else(data_df2[i,"checkin_start"]<=data_df2[i-1,"no_overlap_checkin_end"],data_df2[i-1,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]+1,data_df2[i,"checkin_start"])
    data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_end"]<-data_df2[i,"no_overlap_checkin_start"]+data_df2[i,"boarding_days"]-1
    }
  }
},
dplyr = data_df %>%
  group_by(Guest_ID) %>%
  mutate(no_overlap_checkin_stop = pmax(checkin_date[1] + cumsum(boarding_days) - 1, checkin_date + boarding_days - 1), no_overlap_checkin_start = pmax(lag(no_overlap_checkin_stop) + 1, checkin_date, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  relocate(no_overlap_checkin_start, .before = no_overlap_checkin_stop) %>%
  ungroup(),
data.table = as.data.table(data_df)[, no_overlap_checkin_stop := pmax(checkin_date[1] + cumsum(boarding_days) - 1, checkin_date + boarding_days - 1), by = Guest_ID
    ][, no_overlap_checkin_start := pmax(shift(no_overlap_checkin_stop) + 1, checkin_date, na.rm = TRUE), by = Guest_ID], check=FALSE)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory               time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>               <list>           <list>            
# 1 orig         7.44ms   7.55ms      131.    26.6KB     0       66     0      502ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [103 × 3]> <bench_tm [66]>  <tibble [66 × 3]> 
# 2 dplyr        4.01ms   4.06ms      245.    14.3KB     0      123     0      502ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [45 × 3]>  <bench_tm [123]> <tibble [123 × 3]>
# 3 data.table  628.1µs 701.53µs     1393.    81.2KB     4.41   316     1      227ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [12 × 3]>  <bench_tm [317]> <tibble [317 × 3]>
```

The `data.table` looks significantly faster, though that is "statistically faster". If you can perceive the difference between 4ms and 7.5ms, then you may infer "practically faster", though I suggest it isn't a big factor here.

If we grow the data a few times, we can see more difference:

```r
bigger_df <- do.call(rbind, replicate(1000, data_df, simplify=FALSE))
bench::mark(...)
# # A tibble: 3 × 13
#   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                   time             gc                
#   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                   <list>           <list>            
# 1 orig          5.09s    5.09s     0.196   10.08GB    0.393     1     2      5.09s <NULL> <Rprofmem [152,955 × 3]> <bench_tm [1]>   <tibble [1 × 3]>  
# 2 dplyr        5.23ms   5.58ms   179.       3.71MB    0        90     0    504.1ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [127 × 3]>     <bench_tm [90]>  <tibble [90 × 3]> 
# 3 data.table   2.03ms   2.11ms   471.       4.23MB    0       236     0   500.98ms <NULL> <Rprofmem [97 × 3]>      <bench_tm [236]> <tibble [236 × 3]>
```

With larger data, the use of a `for` loop is significantly worse: not only does it take *significantly* longer (much lower `` `itr/sec` ``), it also uses 3x the memory.

I also think it's much easier to say that we can perceive the difference between 5 seconds and 5.58ms, but I'm not sure the difference between 5.58ms and 2.11ms is big enough to outweigh the benefit of working with either the dplyr or data.table code that feels more comfortable. That is, you're going to have to use and maintain this code, and likely extend it with more features. If you don't fully understand (for instance) the `data.table`-dialect here but the `dplyr` reads easily, then I suggest go with the dplyr so that it's easier to maintain and update/fix as you move forward.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans. Could you kindly elaborate on the data.table method? The dplyr method is clear to me.

Comment: The `data.table` method is just a literal translation of the dplyr code. It uses `data.table::shift` instead of `dplyr::lag`, and `by=` instead of `group_by`, everything else is the same. (Oh, and it uses `[`-chaining instead of `magrittr::%>%`, though it could be modified slightly to use `%>%` if needed for readability.)

Comment: With this operation, I don't see either having a significant advantage over the other for _speed_. If your data is big enough to justify the referential semantics of `data.table`, use that one, otherwise use whichever is more consistent with your current code and more comfortable to you.

Comment: Did you run a `microbenchmark` or similar test on the OP's code vs. these examples?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I just did